# How to build and install R package in ESS?

Tags: ess

Some time ago I've written function to build R package using "CMD INSTALL" the problem is that I can't do the same with ESS. There is function `ess-r-devtools-build` but it seems that it don't actually install the package I'm working on it just build tar.gz file.

How can I build and install R package I'm developing in Emacs ESS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ESS provides the function `ess-r-devtools-load` that will run the function `devtools::load_all()` for you. That will load the current version of your package while you are working on it.

Comment: Do I need to do something extra like first build and then install? Because after calling that function the package is not updated, or maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: `load_all` assumes your current working directory (`getwd`) is the top-level directory of an R package you are developing. If you are, it should (re)load all the code in the package into your current session. That makes it available to you in your current session. I'm not sure if it actually installs the package in a way that you'd have access to it from a different session? I only use it when I'm actively working on a particular package, not to permanently install one or more packages into my R library.

Comment: Thanks for explanation unfortunately I'm not able to stop shiny and install package in same session I need to kill R, it seems that my functions are way better the interactive R in ESS, only I can't use browser(), that's why I wanted to try ESS.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. If Shiny (or any other function) is running, then you can't install a package in the same interactive session. If the Shiny app has an 'exit' feature, you can do that, or `C-c C-c` from the R session to cancel the function that way. If you can expand your question to explain exactly what you're trying to do, we may be able to find a proper answer for you.

Comment: I know that I need to stopy shiny before install I simply don't want to kill R, see this question on SO [How to kill shiny app in ESS without killing R process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31526293/387194) the problem is this don't work.

Comment: If I understand now, the problem really isn't how to load packages, it's how to stop a shiny app without killing R? That's a different question, but one we could probably try to figure out. Or maybe the ESS help mailing list would be a good resource. They're pretty active and helpful: https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/ess-help

Comment: I have two issue, first is that I can't install the package, so I can use in shiny app. I want to actually install the package I'm working on, the R console is of no use if I need to run shell command to run R, maybe there is a way to rest R shell, this is what I need to do If I need to use RStudio and build package in Emacs. The question about killing shiny is for another post.